# How to create a static instance of a dependency injected class?

Tags: c#, constructor, dependency-injection, static-initialization, app.xaml

I've defined a class which takes a repository instance as the sole constructor argument. And now that I created a static instance of that class, `MainViewModel` the constructor arguments need to be specified.

**Issue:**

In order to specify the required arguments, I added the IRepository argument as expected in the static instance of the MainVM class.

This didn't work as expected as the compiler is throwing the following errors as a result of this:

```
Using the generic type 'ParkingTagPicker.DAL.IRepository<T>' requires 1 type arguments  

ParkingTagPicker.Models.Zone' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' 

The name 'zoneDataService' does not exist in the current context
```

From looking at the errors it seems the IRepository is being supplied with the correct `Zone` type.

Does anyone know how to correctly define the constructor args in this situation?

**MainViewModel:**

```
    //IRepository instance with Zone type arg
    //(Zone is a model class)
    private IRepository<Zone> _zoneDataService;

    public MainViewModel(IRepository<Zone> zoneDataService)
    {
        this._zoneDataService = zoneDataService;
    }
```

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A static ViewModel used by the views to bind against.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The MainViewModel object.</returns>
    public static MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            // Delay creation of the view model until necessary
            if (viewModel == null)
                viewModel = new MainViewModel(IRepository<Zone> zoneDataService);

            return viewModel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `viewModel = new MainViewModel(new IRepository<Zone>());`?? (Otherwise, code is illegal)

Comment: I tried that, but I can't new IRepository it is an interface. Any other ideas?

Comment: What concrete type that implements `IRepository<T>` do you expect to use? (`new` *that*).

Comment: The type that implements IRepository<T> is the CouncilZoneRepository. So it implements like so..public class CouncilZoneRespository : IRepository<Zone>. Then I just need to new CouncilZoneRepository<Zone>?

Comment: `new CouncilZoneRepository`. No template type since that type is not templated (it inherits a templated base, but passes it's own type)

Comment: Ok my CouncilZoneRepository provides a static instance. So I tried the following,                     `viewModel = new MainViewModel(CouncilZoneRespository.Instance);`  Should that work in this case?

Comment: I guess so but usage of static instances (and singleton pattern in general) is largely deprecated. You should consider using Factory Pattern and injection instead.